Eureka js client stuck on new promise
like said in the caption I'm having trouble fetching url's from my other registered services.
Here is my Eureka Client configuration in my frontend module. Im using React 18 and Next 14 if that's relevant and host Eureka Server with Spring Boot 3.
import { Eureka } from 'eureka-js-client';

const eurekaClient = new Eureka({
  instance: {
    app: 'TripPlanner',
    hostName: 'localhost', // Or your frontend's actual hostname/IP
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1', // Or your frontend's actual IP
    statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/info',
    port: {
      '$': 3000, // Or your frontend's port
      '@enabled': true,
    },
    vipAddress: 'tripplanner.test.com', // Unique virtual IP
    dataCenterInfo: {
      '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
      name: 'MyOwn',
    },
  },
  eureka: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8761, // Or your Eureka Server port
    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/',
    fetchRegistry: true, // Fetch registry on startup
    registerWithEureka: true, // Register this instance with Eureka
  },
});

eurekaClient.start(error => {
  console.log(error || 'Eureka client started');
});

I'm trying to fetch url to given service with this function but the Promise is being stuck in an unknown point for me because logs in eurekaClient.getInstancesByAppId() show that it does infact retrive correct url.
export async function fetchServiceUrl(serviceName) {

  try {
    const instances = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      eurekaClient.getInstancesByAppId(serviceName, (error, instances) => {
        console.log('Instances 1:', instances);
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error', error);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Instances 2:', instances);
          resolve(instances);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('Instances:', instances);
    if (instances.length === 0) {
      eurekaClient.stop();
      console.log('Service not found, Eureka Client stopped')
      throw new Error(`Service ${serviceName} not found`);
    }

    const instance = instances[0]; // Choose the first instance
    const protocol = instance.securePort ? 'https' : 'http';
    eurekaClient.stop();
    console.log('Service URL:', `${protocol}://${instance.ipAddr}:${instance.port.$}`);
    return `${protocol}://${instance.ipAddr}:${instance.port.$}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching service URL:', error);
    eurekaClient.stop();
    throw error;
  }
}

I do not really know how to move forward with that issue because in Eureka Dashboard all services, including TripPlanner are visible and up and also eurekaClient can discover them but still does not print even 'Instances 1' log nor error in catch block.
I setup cors filter before for Eureka Server because request where blocked from localhost:3000 and also here is my application.yaml for eureka-server module
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false



The documentation for eureka-js-client seems to show that getInstancesByAppId is a synchronous function that just takes one parameter. Shouldn't it be const instances = eurekaClient.getInstancesByAppId(serviceName)?
